# Convert Hex to DIN-Code

Tags: c++

I want convert a HEX-Code to a [DIN ZK-Code](http://www.easyident.de/PDF%20Files/Umrechnung%20easyident%20Ausgabe%20in%20diverse%20Codes.pdf). The calculation is in the picture below.
The Hex-Code gets converted to Binary-Code. After that, it will get reversed bytewise and converted to DEC half-byte-wise.
I have problems here. Even though I would have done a solution to this, it still would be really inefficent. Maybe you can give me hints, on which functions to look at.

[image]

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Can you show us what is wrong with it?

Comment: I can't show you anything. Because it was just bad.

Comment: I tried reading in char array, and then sorting it. But I even get cast errors and stuff. I'm feeling kinda hopeless alone with that problem.

Comment: If you show us the code we can tell what is wrong with it. Without it, it is hard to do anything but give you the solution for free, which is not really what SO is about. Nobody would learn a thing.

Comment: No, I don't want anyone to write it for me. I just want to get hints on which functions to look at. Maybe it is way easier then I imagine with the right functions.

Comment: Break it down into a number of simple functions: (1) convert hex string to array of bytes (2) bit reverse a byte (3) convert string of bytes to 2-character hex nybbles.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Read in the code

You can read all the characters into a `std::string`, so that you have a string containing `"010C2E24DC"`. You can then split this into multiple `std::string`s of two characters each representing a byte using `std::string`s interface.

Step 2: Convert to bytes

You can use a `std::stringstream` to convert strings to numbers, like you can use `std::cin` to read numbers from the console. Fill the `std::stringstream` with a single "byte string" each time, using `std::hex` and `operator<<`, and then parse it into an unsigned char using `operator>>`.

Step 3: Bit shifts

Use a combination of binary operators (e.g. shift (<<, >>), and (&), or (|)) to reverse the order of the bits in each unsigned char.

Step 4: Separate into half-bytes

Again, use a combination of binary operators to convert the bit-reversed unsigned chars into half-bytes.

Step 5: Convert back to string

You can use a `std::stringstream` (or output directly to `std::cout`) by streaming to the numbers into them, converting them to text. You may want to look into `std::setw` to add zero-padding.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something along the lines of what was suggested by Peter

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

std::string hex2din(const char* hex) {
  assert(strlen(hex)==10);

  std::stringstream oss;
  std::stringstream ss;

  std::string hexstr = std::string(hex);

  int halfbyte;

  for (size_t j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++) {
    std::string s = hexstr.substr(2*j,2);
    ss << std::hex << "0x" << s;
    unsigned short rev, tmp=0;
    ss >> rev;
    ss.clear();

    for(size_t i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
      tmp |= ( ((rev & (1<<i))?1:0) << (7-i));
    }
    rev = tmp;

    halfbyte = std::stoi(std::bitset< 4 >(rev >> 4).to_string(), nullptr, 2);
    oss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << halfbyte;

    halfbyte = std::stoi(std::bitset< 4 >(rev & 15).to_string(), nullptr, 2);
    oss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << halfbyte;
  }
  return oss.str();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::string s = hex2din("010C2E24DC");
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I will look at it tomorrow. A lot of stuff, I will learn from this. Thank you and Peter!